# Clustering each group with groupby+apply - performance issue

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I've got a data frame as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {'id': {(1, 0, 'obj11'): '3',
  (1, 0, 'obj12'): '9',
  (1, 0, 'obj13'): '5',
  (1, 0, 'obj14'): '4',
  (1, 0, 'obj15'): '23',
  (1, 0, 'obj16'): '52',
  (1, 0, 'obj17'): '22',
  (1, 0, 'obj18'): '13',
  (1, 0, 'obj19'): '8',
  (1, 0, 'obj20'): '26',
  (1, 1000, 'obj11'): '3',
  (1, 1000, 'obj12'): '9',
  (1, 1000, 'obj13'): '5',
  (1, 1000, 'obj14'): '4',
  (1, 1000, 'obj15'): '23',
  (1, 1000, 'obj16'): '52',
  (1, 1000, 'obj17'): '22',
  (1, 1000, 'obj18'): '13',
  (1, 1000, 'obj19'): '8',
  (1, 1000, 'obj20'): '26',
  (1, 2000, 'obj11'): '3',
  (1, 2000, 'obj12'): '9',
  (1, 2000, 'obj13'): '5',
  (1, 2000, 'obj14'): '4',
  (1, 2000, 'obj15'): '23',
  (1, 2000, 'obj16'): '52',
  (1, 2000, 'obj17'): '22',
  (1, 2000, 'obj18'): '13',
  (1, 2000, 'obj19'): '8',
  (1, 2000, 'obj20'): '26',
  (1, 3000, 'obj11'): '3',
  (1, 3000, 'obj12'): '9',
  (1, 3000, 'obj13'): '5',
  (1, 3000, 'obj14'): '4',
  (1, 3000, 'obj15'): '23',
  (1, 3000, 'obj16'): '52',
  (1, 3000, 'obj17'): '22',
  (1, 3000, 'obj18'): '13',
  (1, 3000, 'obj19'): '8',
  (1, 3000, 'obj20'): '26',
  (1, 4000, 'obj11'): '3',
  (1, 4000, 'obj12'): '9',
  (1, 4000, 'obj13'): '5',
  (1, 4000, 'obj14'): '4',
  (1, 4000, 'obj15'): '23',
  (1, 4000, 'obj16'): '52',
  (1, 4000, 'obj17'): '22',
  (1, 4000, 'obj18'): '13',
  (1, 4000, 'obj19'): '8',
  (1, 4000, 'obj20'): '26'},
 'var': {(1, 0, 'obj11'): 61.05099868774414,
  (1, 0, 'obj12'): 52.6510009765625,
  (1, 0, 'obj13'): 61.422000885009766,
  (1, 0, 'obj14'): 75.99199676513672,
  (1, 0, 'obj15'): 72.30999755859375,
  (1, 0, 'obj16'): 63.79999923706055,
  (1, 0, 'obj17'): 52.604000091552734,
  (1, 0, 'obj18'): 61.02899932861328,
  (1, 0, 'obj19'): 65.16999816894531,
  (1, 0, 'obj20'): 71.26699829101562,
  (1, 1000, 'obj11'): 59.92499923706055,
  (1, 1000, 'obj12'): 49.4630012512207,
  (1, 1000, 'obj13'): 60.25299835205078,
  (1, 1000, 'obj14'): 77.15299987792969,
  (1, 1000, 'obj15'): 73.43199920654297,
  (1, 1000, 'obj16'): 62.207000732421875,
  (1, 1000, 'obj17'): 49.805999755859375,
  (1, 1000, 'obj18'): 60.459999084472656,
  (1, 1000, 'obj19'): 65.0199966430664,
  (1, 1000, 'obj20'): 71.9520034790039,
  (1, 2000, 'obj11'): 58.72600173950195,
  (1, 2000, 'obj12'): 45.98500061035156,
  (1, 2000, 'obj13'): 58.21099853515625,
  (1, 2000, 'obj14'): 78.35800170898438,
  (1, 2000, 'obj15'): 75.06199645996094,
  (1, 2000, 'obj16'): 59.23500061035156,
  (1, 2000, 'obj17'): 46.32699966430664,
  (1, 2000, 'obj18'): 57.902000427246094,
  (1, 2000, 'obj19'): 65.1510009765625,
  (1, 2000, 'obj20'): 72.99099731445312,
  (1, 3000, 'obj11'): 57.47800064086914,
  (1, 3000, 'obj12'): 42.904998779296875,
  (1, 3000, 'obj13'): 55.89699935913086,
  (1, 3000, 'obj14'): 79.41999816894531,
  (1, 3000, 'obj15'): 76.78800201416016,
  (1, 3000, 'obj16'): 55.53099822998047,
  (1, 3000, 'obj17'): 42.67900085449219,
  (1, 3000, 'obj18'): 55.277000427246094,
  (1, 3000, 'obj19'): 65.21199798583984,
  (1, 3000, 'obj20'): 74.27400207519531,
  (1, 4000, 'obj11'): 56.189998626708984,
  (1, 4000, 'obj12'): 41.14099884033203,
  (1, 4000, 'obj13'): 54.09000015258789,
  (1, 4000, 'obj14'): 80.78099822998047,
  (1, 4000, 'obj15'): 78.38999938964844,
  (1, 4000, 'obj16'): 57.492000579833984,
  (1, 4000, 'obj17'): 40.400001525878906,
  (1, 4000, 'obj18'): 53.159000396728516,
  (1, 4000, 'obj19'): 63.72200012207031,
  (1, 4000, 'obj20'): 75.40399932861328}}
)
df.index.names = ['k', 'group', 'object']
```

I'd like to cluster objects within groups, so I defined a function that clusters a group.

```
def cluster_group(x, index):
    clustering = KMeans(n_clusters = 3, random_state = 42).fit(x.values)
    return pd.Series(clustering.labels_, index = index)
```

and applied it to my `df` as below:

```
df \ 
    .groupby(['k', 'group']) \ 
    .filter(lambda x: x.shape[0] > 3)['var'] \ 
    .reset_index('object') \ 
    .groupby(['k', 'group']) \ 
    .apply(lambda x: cluster_group(x['var'], x['object']))
```

However, as the original `DataFrame` is quite huge, this solution works really slow. Therefore, I'd like to ask if there's a way to optimise the performance somehow?

My Machine is Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz with 6 cores and 12 threads.`df.shape` is `(1286135, 9)`, but I need to calculate this for many data frames, each of them is around this size. So I need to make sure that the code is as optimal as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Your initial solution is not bad. 
I tried using the `pd.DataFrame.unstack()` method to go a little faster.

Possible solution:

`df = df.unstack()['var'].apply(lambda x: cluster_group(x, x.index), axis=1)`

---

Speed test with the example above:

```
%timeit -n 10 test = df \
    .groupby(['k', 'group']) \
    .filter(lambda x: x.shape[0] > 3)['var'] \
    .reset_index('object') \
    .groupby(['k', 'group']) \
    .apply(lambda x: cluster_group(x['var'], x['object']))
```

234 ms ± 20.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

```
%timeit -n 10 test = df.unstack()['var'].apply(lambda x: cluster_group(x, x.index), axis=1)
```

205 ms ± 26.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)